# maintaining currency amounts in my web application

Tags: javascript, forms, web-applications

This is more like a design problem than technical, of maintaining currency amounts in my web application.

The scenario is - I am bringing some currency amount in a html form. The form is organised as a table of rows with few amounts as read only and others to be filled in by user. After proposing starting estimates, I have to update read only fields based on user input. The amounts on UI are number showing decimal point between dollars  and cents but on backend these amounts are being calculated as integers.

Here is am example, if 2 numbers 3.33 and 6.60 are to be added and sum is to be displayed.

These 2 numbers are first changed to 333 and 660, then added and then converted to 9.93 using text manipulations.

Can someone please propose a design level solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floats are a poor choice for currency because they cannot accurately represent all decimal values without rounding. Better to use BigDecimal.

I'm not sure why you need integers on the backend to correctly do calculations with decimal currency values, but you have your choice of either rounding the numbers, or just taking their integer parts (truncating the decimals).

Comment: May be I lacked expressing myself completely. I know the problem with floats and so I am using 100 times integer values to represent floats. So what looks as 40.05 on screen would be maintained in db as 4005.

Comment: Use bigdecimal everywhere - then there's no conversion needed.

Comment: I am using plain PHP with no framework on server side and Javascript and Jquery on client side. All this manipulation has to happen on client side. I do not know about BigDecimal but based on google search I come know it is available with Java which I am not using.

Comment: sorry - not sure why I assumed server-side java. For javascript, take a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/bcmath-js/ to get arbitrary-precision numerics, and for PHP, look at http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php